# calling a class method - too many input arguments

Tags: matlab

I have a created a simple class to try and learn more about classes in MATLAB

Below is my class.

```
classdef ClassTest < handle

methods             
   function t1 = testone(numOne, numTwo)
      t1 = t2(numOne, numTwo); 
   end

   function t2 = testtwo(numOne, numTwo)
       t2 = numOne / numTwo;
   end
end

end
```

So I create an instance of my class using the line of code below.

```
myClass = ClassTest;
```

I then call the function testone with the line below.

```
v = myClass.testone(20,5);
```

But get the error message "Error using ClassTest/testone Too many input arguments." I don't understand this?

I tried leaving the 5 out and it actually got to the line t1 = t2(numOne, numTwo) but then didn't recognize the function t2 which I find surprising? Not following what is going on here?

**Update**

If I make the methods static I no longer get the error message about there being to many input arguments however it does not recognise the testtwo function when called from the function testone unless I put ClassTest.testtwo. Still seems strange to me

**Solution**

So bit of playing around I now have the code working however not sure I fully understand what is happening.

The two functions should look like below,

```
   function t1 = testone(obj, numOne, numTwo)
      t1 = obj.testtwo(numOne, numTwo);           
   end

   function t2 = testtwo(obj, numOne, numTwo)
       t2 = numOne / numTwo;
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the methods to be static methods of the class, then define them within a methods block as follows:

```
methods (Static)
```

You will then need to call them with the class name as `t1 = ClassTest.testone(20,5)` and `t2 = ClassTest.testtwo(20,5)`.

If instead you want them to be methods of the class, then you would typically define them with the following signature:

```
function t1 = testone(obj, numOne, numTwo)
```

You can then create an instance of the class with `myClass = ClassTest` and call `t1 = myClass.testone(20,5)`.

The object `myClass` is passed into the method as its first argument (I always use the name `obj` as a first argument, but others use things such as `this`, by analogy with Java conventions), and is then available throughout the method code.

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with how matlab loads classes. If you already have myClass in memory and then you create/modify the function definitions, you will likely get an error.

here is more details on how matlab deals with updating classes: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-and-reloading-classes.html

Try clearing all your variables from memory (and as a last resort restarting matlab), and try again.

Comment: Hi, I restarted my matlab just to be safe but still get the same error message though